# How to perform two group classification with deep neural network? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, networking, machine-learning, classification, deep-learning

I'm new in machine learning (and to stackoverflow as well) and i want to make some classification tasks. I performed two group classifications on my data set (field of speech acoustics) with LIBSVM and Matlab's Pattern Recignition Tool from the Neural network toolbox to create a simple network with one hidden layer. In the hope of higher classification results i want to try Deep Neural Networks, and i found this code: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42853-deep-neural-network

I have some difficulty understanding it.

My data is constructed of 127 samples of 19 parameters, so my input number is 19. I want to classify them in two groups: 0 and 1, so my output number is 1. The values in my data set are normalized between 0 and 1.

My code is the following:

```
clear all
clc

addpath('..');
load('data.mat')

inputdata = inputs;
outputdata = outputs;

datanum = 127;
outputnum = 1;
hiddennum = 3;
inputnum = 19;

% rbm = randRBM(inputnum, outputnum);
% rbm = pretrainRBM( rbm, inputdata );

dbn = randDBN([inputnum, hiddennum, outputnum]);
dbn = pretrainDBN( dbn, inputdata );
dbn = SetLinearMapping( dbn, inputdata, outputdata );
dbn = trainDBN( dbn, inputdata, outputdata );

estimate = v2h( dbn, inputdata )
[rmse AveErrNum] = CalcRmse(dbn, inputdata, outputdata)
```

The code runs. The rmse is 0.4183, the AveErrNum is 0.1969. What i need is the classification accuracy between my targets (stored in outputdata) and  the networks predictions (Accuracy = data classified correctly / all data).
Where do i find the networks predictions after binarization?

Do I use the right type of network for my classification?
Don't I need to divide my data into Training, Validation and Testing samples (like in the case of a simple neural network with one hidden layer)?

Thanks in advance for any help!